# C++: boost::asio : what's the maximum buffer size I can use for TCP sockets?

Tags: c++, boost, buffer, boost-asio

In this [SSL client example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp), the default buffer size is 1K=1024 bytes. Are there any practical limitations on how much I could increase that? Would it work fine with no unforeseeable problems if I set the buffer to something like 100 MB?

Notice that the buffer is not just the reserved size; it is also passed to `read()` and `write()`. At what size would these functions face problems due to size limitations? Does such a limitation exist? I can imagine that there is at least a defined limit for how much I can `write()`.

Comment: To infinity, and beyond.  The odds that it ever be filled are zilch.  A good buffer size is 4096 bytes.  Strikes a good balance between not tickling the OS too often and not junking the L1 cache.

Comment: Often times, the application protocol's characteristics helps guide one to the _best_ reserved buffer size.  Also, note that the example's `max_length` is only used for both the local buffer reservation and to enforce a limit on the application protocol (`getline()`).  The size of the buffer being passed to the read and write operations is the calculated request length, which may be smaller than `max_length`.

Comment: @TannerSansbury Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit other than the maximum value of an `int`, but a read buffer larger than the socket receive buffer is pointless, as the excess can never be used.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Could you please further tell me, how big is the socket buffer? Where can I get that number? And will the program still work without losing data even if I write 100 MB to the socket?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist The size of the network stack buffer for both the local sender and remote receiver is implementation dependent and may require consulting the implementation documentation.  As part of the TCP protocol handling, written data will not be lost.  `write()` will block until room is available within the local network stack's write buffer.

Comment: @BryanO'Neil There were no grammar errors to fix. Edit rejected.